# How to define a secondary y-axis when plotting with Kusto Query Language (KQL)

Tags: azure, plot, azure-data-explorer, kql

I was wondering if there is a way to create a secondary y-axis when plotting query results by Kusto Query Language. In particular via using the Kusto Explorer or Azure Web UI.

My data table has time-series variables whose magnitudes are significantly different. I would like to see all these variables in the same line-plot or time-chart therefore,require a secondary y-axis.

I have gone through the instructions given in the 'render' documentation (see the link below), however was unable to create a secondary y-axis (the argument such as ysplit didn't produce what I am looking for).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/renderoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer

Would be great if someone can let me know whether this is possible, or do I have to use another tool such as PowerBI or Python to achieve this.

Thank you

Comment: ysplit works for me. can you maybe change this toy example such that it won't work? https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA02OwQrCMBBE7/mKObYSNK22SqH/4F08xGaxgRBLErWVfrzRqMgedt7OzrJKhlgnQ8iUnBpoGzgGpztqoC7XaOQHVnAUQoil4GAlR/nV6zRPsElGgoqj%20kH9WUu0/bd2HHUCdsQMT05Lox8UNY2BrELXS3umPbmObECbfsMqdrplb8ixeN1nM1wMkIPRlmLMBdx16JFNfjA6tHIknz8BFj49c/AAAAA=

Comment: thank you Rony. I have written an example specific to the problem I am referring to in the same help/samples page (please let me know if you can't see it for any reason). I am not clear on how to assign specific variables to right or left axis. thank you

Comment: you'd have to click on share => generate link and paste it here

Comment: Thank you Rony, here is the link: https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA32S3YqDMBCF732KubOFdBsTpSD0vu+wLJKtUw34t8nsWmEffqNSMCpLcjHOOcN3ZHI+w63tgVpQ1uqigYfBrywC1eRzKUbN6KIkGE7qqe0kdW2PZqoMqjvpH8zmljNTiVDh4+UPckXufFYIB9I1WlJ1l4Lr4vjJYMSqKqOhwxQsGd0UDGpU9ttgjQ2lI6M6vgeh4IKfeORuyCCcgK6IBOfAdtXslc51Es43pvlnJ/EtYrAri1kWy2Hh8eWKL3b5UvKNacmPPb5Y8+VyWHr8ZMWXu3yR8I1pyeeJF0CuA0TL6fjfAPFugIu/gHizAD9AvNlAwoIP+DXY5ONDc2/nXipD0Gsq4TDYrtIEV1BPtMc/LqB479cCAAA=

Comment: looks like there are 4 axes in the result - so seems like each line has its own axis. Is that not what you want?

Comment: thanks Rony. At moment I can't control which variable to assign to which axis. I would like to have freq_1 and freq_2 on the right axis as they have similar magnitudes. Other two variables: power and reactive power on the left axis as they have similar magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

The following code can get you some of the way there, which may be enough, but the splitting of axes is a bit limited in the UI and the code generation. This answer is based on the sample code you posted in your comment:

## All Signal Types on Separate Axes

Here we create separate columns for each measurement depending on signal type. The rendering will occur in the order in which the columns appear so you will get `power` as main axis (left) and `power_reactive, freq_1, freq_2` as their own separate axes on the right.

```
datatable (timestamp: datetime, signal_type: string, measurement: real)[
'2020-01-01', 'power', 1200 ,
'2020-01-01', 'power_reactive', 500,
'2020-01-01', 'freq_1', 50.1, 
'2020-01-01', 'freq_2', 50.2,
'2020-01-02', 'power', 1300 ,
'2020-01-02', 'power_reactive', 330,
'2020-01-02', 'freq_1', 50.4, 
'2020-01-02', 'freq_2', 50.3,
'2020-01-03', 'power', 1500 ,
'2020-01-03', 'power_reactive', 250,
'2020-01-03', 'freq_1', 50.05, 
'2020-01-03', 'freq_2', 50.1,
'2020-01-04', 'power', 1500 ,
'2020-01-04', 'power_reactive', 700,
'2020-01-04', 'freq_1', 50.15, 
'2020-01-04', 'freq_2', 50.25,
]
| project timestamp,
          power_measurement = iif(signal_type == "power", measurement, real(null)),
          power_reactive_measurement = iif(signal_type == "power_reactive", measurement, real(null)),
          freq_1_measurement = iif(signal_type == "freq_1", measurement, real(null)),
          freq_2_measurement = iif(signal_type == "freq_2", measurement, real(null))
|render timechart with (ysplit =axes, ytitle="power")
```

[image: Chart with each column on a separate y-axis]

## Combine multiple signals into the main y-axis

Using the web-ui you can render the above code and then delete the `reactive-power` y-axis, which will combine it back into the main y-axis and will display that signal on the same scale:

[image: Location of deletion button for reactive power axis]

This will result in the following plot with 3 axes:

1. the main y-axis on the left containing power and power reactive
   and
2. an axis on the right showing freq_1
3. an axis on the right showing freq_2

[image: Image showing the power and reactive power on the same scale]